# Parsing XML with XMLNS in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm fairly new to querying XML datatypes. We receive XMLs from partners and one such partner sends us XMLs like this:

```
DECLARE @ResultData XML = '<outGoing xmlns="urn:testsystems-com:HH.2015.Services.Telephony.OutGoing">
    <customer>
        <ID>158</ID>
    </customer>
</outGoing>'
```

In this example, I would like to pull only the ID out of the XML, but it seems the xmlns is preventing me from getting anything inside the XML:

```
SELECT cust.value('(ID)[1]', 'VARCHAR(40)') as 'CustomerID'
FROM    @ResultData.nodes('/outGoing/customer') as t(cust)
```

returns NUll, but if I *manually* remove the XMLNS from the XML I get 158.

I've experimented with `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` to see if I could use that, but I'm obviously missing something.  Since these XMLs will be coming in automatically, I would like to be able to parse the XML, but right now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work:

```
DECLARE @ResultData XML = '<outGoing xmlns="urn:testsystems-com:HH.2015.Services.Telephony.OutGoing">
    <customer>
        <ID>158</ID>
    </customer>
</outGoing>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:testsystems-com:HH.2015.Services.Telephony.OutGoing')
SELECT
     @ResultData.value('(/outGoing/customer/ID)[1]', 'int')
```

or to use your approach:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:testsystems-com:HH.2015.Services.Telephony.OutGoing')
SELECT 
    CustomerID = cust.value('(ID)[1]', 'INT') 
FROM    
    @ResultData.nodes('/outGoing/customer') as t(cust)
```

This will return `158` as its value.

I've used `WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT .....)` since this is the only XML namespace in play, and it's defined at the top-level node - so it applies to every node in the XML structure.

Comment: Thank you @Marc! Saved my bacon on that one-and my sanity.  So even though it is declared in the top-level node in the xml, it doesn't automatically apply to every other node in the structure and you have to explicitly declare it?

Comment: @user3333088: when a XML namespace is defined on a node, it's "inherited" down to all child nodes - unless a child node explicitly defines something else. So here, really all the XML nodes are part of that defined XML namespace - since it's defined without an explicit prefix (`xmlns="...."`) it's automatically applied to all child nodes.